# What is the best way of Under sampling in R

Tags: r, random, analytics, data-science

I have a dataset with attribute A,B, C. C is a factor with 2 labels zz and z. `number of (z) > number of (zz)`, I want to **under sample** my data set so that in the new data has same no of zz and z values. **Can't use any external package** for this. *Best if can be done using `sample` function*

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Attribute A   |   Attribute B . | Attribute c  |
--------------------------------------------------
|  xx           | y1              | zz           |
--------------------------------------------------
|  mm           | r1              |  z           |
--------------------------------------------------
|  ab           | 1r              |  z           |
--------------------------------------------------
|  ry           | cm              |  zz          |
--------------------------------------------------
|  ca           | rx              |  z           |
--------------------------------------------------
|  mm           | zr              |  z           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

And the result should be-

---

```
| Attribute A   |   Attribute B . | Attribute c  |
--------------------------------------------------
|  xx           | y1              | zz           |
--------------------------------------------------
|  mm           | r1              |  z           |
--------------------------------------------------
|  ab           | 1r              |  z           |
--------------------------------------------------
|  ry           | cm              |  zz          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Here probability of zz = probability  of z = 0.5

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your data looks like. Please provide some reproducible data, either as the output of `dput` or code to generate a larger random sample. Also include your expected output. What code have you tried so far to sample it?

Comment: @sapy you can try something like `sample(C$x, length(C$y))` where, `C$x` is the x values in your C vector and `C$y` is the y values in your vector. Without your dataset or an example of the dataset, it is not possible to provide an proper answer.

Comment: check the `ROSE` package, `smote` in `DmwR` package or `downSample` and `upSample` in the `caret` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your data is in a data frame called `data` with columns `A`, `B`, and `C`, you can do something like:

```
## rows that have "z" and "zz" entries
z_ind <- which(data$C == "z")
zz_ind <- which(data$C == "zz")

nsamp <- 10   #number of elements to sample
## if you want all elements of the smaller class, could be:
## nsamp <- min(length(z_ind), length(zz_ind))

## select `nsamp` entries with "z" and `nsamp` entries with "zz"
pick_z <- sample(z_ind, nsamp)
pick_zz <- sample(zz_ind, nsamp)

new_data <- data[c(pick_z, pick_zz), ]
```

Comment: How will it ensure there is 50% probability of z and zz in new data ? Thats my main concern

Comment: what do you mean? you are grabbing `nsamp` entries of each, so they will always be evenly split. Or did I misunderstand what you wanted the output to be?